# Adding always the half of the previous number to a number beginning with 1...

Tags: arithmetic, infinity

This question blows my mind.

Let's say we start at 1 and keep adding always 0.5 * the previous number.

1 + 0.5 + 0.25 + 0.125 + .....

The question is: **will it reach infinity?**

I really don't know, kept thinking about this alot.

Comment: Do you know what a geometric progression is?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF

Comment: It will never reach $2$.  At each step, so go half the remaining distance to $2$, so you never get there.

Comment: Are you familiar with proof by induction?

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite it with fractions and it might be a bit clearer:

$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} ...$

Now calculate the partial sums:

$1$, $1 \frac{1}{2}$, $1 \frac{3}{4}$, $1 \frac{7}{8}$, $1 \frac{15}{16}$, ...

See a pattern?  Can you see this going over $2$?  How close do you think it might get?

Answer (score 2):

Consider calculating the sum in steps, at each step adding the next term. At the $n^{th}$ step, you're adding $1/2^n$ (adding $1$ is the $0^{th}$ step). Then at the $n^{th}$ step, the total sum is the following:

$$
s_n = 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n}
$$

Now remark that you can perform the following calculation:

\begin{align*}
1 + \frac{1}{2} s_n &= 1 + \frac{1}{2}
\left(
1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n}
\right)
\\
&=
1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + ... + \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
\\
&= s_n + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
\end{align*}

Then if you solve for $s_n$ using elementary algebra (which you can do since $s_n$ is finite), you end up with:

$$
s_n = 2 - \frac{1}{2^n} < 2
$$
What we have just shown is that $s_n \leq 2$ for any $n$ that we choose. In other words, no matter how many terms we add, the resulting sum will always be less than $2$. ***So, the sum will not reach infinity.***

Answer (score -1):

So what you're looking for is the value of this series, which will call it $S$.

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n=1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...$$

If we divide this value $S$ by $2$ we get

$$\frac{S}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...=S-1 \Longrightarrow S=2S-1$$

so now with simple algebra we get the result that the sum of these numbers $S$ tends to $2$, which is not $\infty$.

Comment: In order to perform algebraic manipulations with $S$ you need to assume that it is a finite number, which defeats the purpose. Rather, once we've established that $S$ is finite, we can use this argument to conclude $S=2$.

Comment: I know, but for that I would have to have proved that the corresponding sequence converges, and I don't think it needed this much detail. I know it wasn't totally mathematically rigorous but OK if you want to downvote good for you.

Comment: The question asked whether the sum converged. You didn't show that wasn't the case, so I don't believe you answered the question in a satisfactory way.